# PHP - get_headers() return wrong result when non-UTF symbols are in URL

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, get-headers

I stumbled upon the wrong result of `get_headers()` method.

URL for testing: http://www.zakon.hr/z/199/Zakon-o-elektroni%C4%8Dkoj-trgovini

Here's simple curl request to that URL:

[image]

As you can see on screenshot there's successful response with 200 OK code.

But if I using `get_headers()` for the same URL I'm getting anothere result:

```
var_dump(get_headers('http://www.zakon.hr/z/199/Zakon-o-elektroničkoj-trgovini'));

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request"
  [1]=>
  string(23) "Cache-Control: no-cache"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "Connection: close"
  [3]=>
  string(23) "Content-Type: text/html"
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: This is not the same URL. The `č` needs to be percent-encoded.

Comment: @lafor danm, how can I miss that :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last term contains UTF-8 data which needs to be properly encoded.  This works:

```
var_dump(get_headers('http://www.zakon.hr/z/199/' . 
    rawurlencode('Zakon-o-elektroničkoj-trgovini')
));
```

Produces this output:

```
array(11) {
  [0] =>
  string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  [1] =>
  string(73) "Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA; Path=/; HttpOnly"
  [2] =>
  string(100) "Set-Cookie: AAAA=AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA; Expires=Wed, 09-Apr-2025 14:57:24 GMT; Path=/"
  [3] =>
  string(37) "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8"
  [4] =>
  string(23) "Content-Language: en-US"
  [5] =>
  string(21) "Content-Length: 74205"
  [6] =>
  string(21) "Vary: Accept-Encoding"
  [7] =>
  string(35) "Date: Mon, 01 Jun 2015 14:57:24 GMT"
  [8] =>
  string(17) "Connection: close"
  [9] =>
  string(22) "Server: lighttpd/2.0.0"
  [10] =>
  string(43) "Set-Cookie: LBSERVERID=srv2-zakonhr; path=/"
}
```