# PHP - `get_headers` returns "400 Bad Request" and "403 Forbidden" for valid URLs?

Tags: php, get-headers

**Working solution at bottom of description!**

I am running PHP 5.4, and trying to get the headers of a list of URLs.

For the most part, everything is working fine, but there are three URLs that are causing issues (and likely more, with more extensive testing).

```
'http://www.alealimay.com'
'http://www.thelovelist.net'
'http://www.bleedingcool.com'
```

All three sites work fine in a browser, and produce the following header responses:

*(From Safari)*

[image: successful headers]

Note that all three header responses are `Code = 200`

But retrieving the headers via PHP, using [`get_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)...

```
stream_context_set_default(array('http' => array('method' => "HEAD")));
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
stream_context_set_default(array('http' => array('method' => "GET")));
```

... returns the following:

```
url  ......  "http://www.alealimay.com"

headers
|    0  ............................  "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"
|    content-length  ...............  "378"
|    X-Synthetic  ..................  "true"
|    expires  ......................  "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC"
|    pragma  .......................  "no-cache"
|    cache-control  ................  "no-cache, must-revalidate"
|    content-type  .................  "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
|    connection  ...................  "close"
|    date  .........................  "Wed, 24 Aug 2016 01:26:21 UTC"
|    X-ContextId  ..................  "QIFB0I8V/xsTFMREg"
|    X-Via  ........................  "1.0 echo109"
   


url  ......  "http://www.thelovelist.net"

headers
|    0  ............................  "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"
|    content-length  ...............  "378"
|    X-Synthetic  ..................  "true"
|    expires  ......................  "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC"
|    pragma  .......................  "no-cache"
|    cache-control  ................  "no-cache, must-revalidate"
|    content-type  .................  "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
|    connection  ...................  "close"
|    date  .........................  "Wed, 24 Aug 2016 01:26:22 UTC"
|    X-ContextId  ..................  "aNKvf2RB/bIMjWyjW"
|    X-Via  ........................  "1.0 echo103"



url  ......  "http://www.bleedingcool.com"

headers
|    0  ............................  "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"
|    Server  .......................  "Sucuri/Cloudproxy"
|    Date  .........................  "Wed, 24 Aug 2016 01:26:22 GMT"
|    Content-Type  .................  "text/html"
|    Content-Length  ...............  "5311"
|    Connection  ...................  "close"
|    Vary  .........................  "Accept-Encoding"
|    ETag  .........................  "\"57b7f28e-14bf\""
|    X-XSS-Protection  .............  "1; mode=block"
|    X-Frame-Options  ..............  "SAMEORIGIN"
|    X-Content-Type-Options  .......  "nosniff"
|    X-Sucuri-ID  ..................  "11005"
```

This is the case regardless of changing the stream_context

```
//stream_context_set_default(array('http' => array('method' => "HEAD")));
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
//stream_context_set_default(array('http' => array('method' => "GET")));
```

Produces the same result.

No warnings or errors are thrown for any of these (normally have the errors suppressed with `@get_headers`, but there is no difference either way).

I have checked my `php.ini`, and have [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) set to `On`.

I am headed towards [`stream_get_meta_data`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111770/php-differences-between-get-headers-and-stream-get-meta-data), *and am not interested in `CURL` solutions*. `stream_get_meta_data` (and its accompanying `fopen`) will fail in the same spot as `get_headers`, so fixing one will fix both in this case.

Usually, if there are redirects, the output looks like:

```
url  ......  "http://www.startingURL.com/"

headers
|    0  ............................  "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"
|    1  ............................  "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
|    Date
|    |    "Wed, 24 Aug 2016 02:02:29 GMT"
|    |    "Wed, 24 Aug 2016 02:02:32 GMT"
|    
|    Server
|    |    "Apache"
|    |    "Apache"
|    
|    Location  .....................  "http://finishingURL.com/"
|    Connection
|    |    "close"
|    |    "close"
|    
|    Content-Type
|    |    "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
|    |    "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
|    
|    Link  .........................  "; rel=\"https://api.w.org/\", ; rel=shortlink"
```

**How come the sites work in browsers, but fail when using `get_headers`?**

There are various SO posts discussing the same thing, but the solution for all of them doesn't pertain to this case:

[`POST` requires `Content-Length`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916404/http-request-failed-in-php-bad-request?answertab=votes#tab-top) (I'm sending a `HEAD` request, no content is returned)

[URL contains UTF-8 data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576588/php-get-headers-return-wrong-result-when-non-utf-symbols-are-in-url?answertab=votes#tab-top) (The only chars in these URLs are all from the Latin alphabet)

[Cannot send a URL with spaces in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/why-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed#answer-697498) (These URLs are all space-free, and very ordinary in every way)

## Solution!

*(Thanks to Max in the answers below for pointing me on the right track.)*

The issue is because there is no pre-defined `user_agent`, without either setting on in `php.ini`, or declaring it in code.

So, I change the `user_agent` to mimic a browser, do the deed, and then revert it back to stating value (likely blank).

```
$OriginalUserAgent = ini_get('user_agent');
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0');

$headers = @get_headers($url, 1);

ini_set('user_agent', $OriginalUserAgent);
```

User agent change found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403025/how-to-set-user-agent-for-get-headers-php-function).

Comment: Don't forget accept answer

Comment: @waki, the answer isn't correct, and uses `curl`, which I explicitly said I didn't want to use. As mentioned, it pointed me in the right direction, and I've given credit and thanks where due, instead of down-voting it.

Comment: you can publish your answer and accept him, for make question as solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because all three these sites are checking UserAgent header of the request and response with an error in that case if it could not be matched. `get_headers` function do not send this header. You may try cURL and this code snippet for getting content of the sites:

```
$url = 'http://www.alealimay.com';
$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'curl/7.48.0');
curl_exec($c);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($c));
```

**UPD:**
It's not necessary to use cURL for setting user agent header. It can be also done with `ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0');` and then `get_headers` function will use configured value.

Comment: The code you've supplied, taken verbatim, prints the entire website. It's a waste to get all that data, when I'm only interested in the header. You [put me on the right track through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403025/how-to-set-user-agent-for-get-headers-php-function).

Comment: If you change your answer to not use `curl`, and reflect the solution I've posted at the tail-end of the original question, I'll give you the accept. But as it stands right now, this only helped and was not an appropriate solution based on the information in the question.